# MYSQL: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

this should be working but I get an error somehow. I want to get the credits column from the table and multiply it by 100. The problem is to get the number of credits for a given student id and year and get the total payment. Assuming each credit is $100.

```
delimiter //
create function fTest (stuYear varchar(4), stuID varchar(4))
returns varchar(200)
begin
declare msg varchar(200) default '';
if (stuYear = '' or stuYear is null) then 
    select 'Please input a valid year' into msg;
elseif (stuID = '' or stuID is null) then 
    select 'Please input a student  id' into msg;    
else
begin

if (msg = '' or msg is null) then
    select ('No result found for student ID: ', stuID, ' at year: ', stuYear) into msg; 
select (credits * 100) into msg from Students_Courses natural join Courses where sid=stuID and year=stuYear group by credits;
return msg ;    
end if;    
end ;
end if;
end ;
//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
select ('No result found for student ID: ', stuID, ' at year: ', stuYear)
```

A select statement can contain multiple columns, but you shouldn't enclose them in parentheses. Also, that would return multiple values, which you can't select into a single message.

So, I guess you wanted to concat the values into a single value. You can do that using the `concat` function, like so:

```
select concat('No result found for student ID: ', stuID, ' at year: ', stuYear)
```

Btw, a normal assignment using the concat function should also work in a trigger:

```
SET msg = concat('No result found for student ID: ', stuID, ' at year: ', stuYear);
```

See [MySQL concat function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

PS: In the next statement, you also got parentheses: `(credits * 100)` 
In this case it accidentally will work, because it's a single expression. They don't have any functional value, though, and might as well be removed.

Comment: @Jay2019 . . . If this answers your question, you should consider accepting the answer.